# Promise loops (bluebird) - wrap object in async

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have a question about promises.

I am using Bluebird Promise library and build *a small **async** library* with it.

I am trying to waterfall promises with the use of a function.

Say I use promises like so:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function () {
  console.log("called 1")
  return 1;
}).then(function () {
  return new Promise (function (res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("called 2")
      res(2);  
    }, 1500);
  });
}).then(function () {
  console.log("called 3")
  return 3;
});
```

This does in fact wait in a loop and return 1,2,3 in order.

How do I wrap it into a function so that I can do something like this:

`a();b();c();`, or `a().b().c();` where a() puts something onto a chain, b() puts something onto a chain, and c() puts something onto a chain in order.

Since then() returns a new promise, it can all go out of order, so something like
does not work:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
function a () {
  promise.then(function () { 
    // do sync/async 
  });
}
function b () {
  promise.then(function () {
    //do sync/async
  });
}
function c ...
```

Thank you for your time :]

> I'm not sure what the goal is here. Do you want to have an arbitrary number of things run in sequence where the sequence is known in advance? Or is this a case where the sequence is discovered as you go? The NodeJS streams interface is a lot better for processing an unknown number of things sequentially (@tadman)

Sequence is discoverable, goal is to have ability to call `a().b().c()` or `b().a().d()`. Async library on a client-side.

**Update**: <del>If I do as @zerkms says it does not work as expected</del>. My bad, should work ok, but with lack of context/code did not give me enough info to expand on. Still thank you for your answer, as it gave me more food for thought.

**Update**: See my answer

Comment: `function a(promise) { return promise.then(...); }`

Comment: If you return a promise inside of a `then` block, that promise will be executed before the chain continues. Usually this allows you to arbitrarily branch as required. Keep in mind you must explicitly return this new promise or it won't chain properly. Your approach here with `getNext` keeps branching, it doesn't chain.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I can update promise each time I call it, like in my Update. Seems legit? It does work, btw, thanks

Comment: so I've added ```chainPromise()``` to make it update ```this.promise``` with new ```promise``` from ```then``` and chain on top of it, looks legit?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is here. Do you want to have an arbitrary number of things run in sequence where the sequence is known in advance? Or is this a case where the sequence is discovered as you go? The NodeJS streams interface is a lot better for processing an unknown number of things sequentially.

Comment: sequence is discoverable and run on client. goal is to wrap object into async sequence so I can call it like ```a().b().c()``` or ```c().a().d()``` or whatnot.
How would streams help me in this case? (no pun intended)

Comment: "If I do as @zerkms says it does not work as expected." --- do we need to guess how exactly you implemented it? Since my code is correct.

Comment: sure, marked it as such, no offense please :]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [scoped prototype](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#for-library-authors) and just add those methods there

```
Promise.prototype.a = function() {
  return this.then(function() {
    console.log("called 1")
    return 1;
  });
};

Promise.prototype.b = function() {
  return this.delay(1500).then(function() {
    console.log("called 2")
    return 1;
  });
};

Promise.prototype.c = function() {
  return this.then(function() {
    console.log("called 3")
    return 3;
  });
};
```

I use this to create neat DSLs e.g. with git:

https://gist.github.com/petkaantonov/6a73bd1a35d471ddc586

Comment: very near version bumping :]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tadman I came up with this so far, seems to work as I expect it to.
The problem was that I did not update the promise before calling then on it, and it was branching instead of calling it in sequence.
And this is what I wanted - to turn an object that has both sync/async into async to allow chaining. Petka (@Esailija) also shows great example of building DSLs above (semvar version bumping & git pushing) by extending bluebird library, but for my purposes this is enough.

```
var Sample = function () {
  this.promise = Promise.resolve();
};

Sample.prototype.a = function () {
  this.then(function () {
    console.log("1");
  });
  return this;
};

Sample.prototype.b = function () {
  this.then(function () {
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("2");
        res();
      }, 500);
    });
  });
  return this;
};

Sample.prototype.c = function () {
  this.then(function () {
    console.log("3");
  })
  return this;
};

Sample.prototype.chainPromise = function (func) {
  this.promise = this.promise.then(func);
};

var s = new Sample();
s.a().b().c();
```

or even then instead of chainPromise?

```
Sample.prototype.then = function (func) {
  this.promise = this.promise.then(func);
  return this.promise;
};
```

Comment: Your `chainPromise` method should work, I wonder why you don't use it for your `a`,`b`,`c` methods in your example?

Comment: yeah, its either chainPromise or then which is kinda same :]